# Use google calendar with Symfony

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, symfony

I want to access to the calendar to read/create event from the user if he agrees.

I've followed the guide https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync
I've actived the api with my google account. Then use the OAuth 2.0 to get a code and the token.
When I follow the test, I use another account to simulate a random user.

Arrived at the lecture of the agenda, I get this error:

> Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true&timeMin=2016-06-14T11%3A28%3A25%2B02%3A00: (403) Access Not Configured. Calendar API has not been used in project 1056... before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?project=1056... then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

It seems legit but I don't want the user to active the api on his side...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Developers console and enable the Google Calendar API. You need to tell Google which APIs your application will be accessing.

Comment: As I said I did it. The problem is it asks me to activate it for other user.

Comment: This message has nothing to do with the User.  This message is your application on Google Developer console that is not set up correctly.   Every user is going to have to approve your application no matter what but that's not what this message is saying.    Do what the message says https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?project=1056 activate it.